# After Ubuntu update from 15 to 16.04, error in keyboard-configuration package

Tags: updates, dpkg, 16.04

So I just started the automatic upgrade of my Ubuntu distribution this morning, from 15.xx to the new 16.04, everything went smoothly except for an error I got at the end: something prevented the full installation of the keyboard-configuration package (didn't get a screenshot of the error).

It also mentioned that since the installation could not be completed, it was reverted. I restarted my computer and on the login screen I immediately saw two things:

1. It's using the default resolution with no options to increase it (and only one of my two screens is detected), meaning that probably the display driver is not working properly.
2. It indicates that it is using the 16.04 distribution, so it seems like it was updated after all.

I then went in a terminal to try and figure out why my displays were not working properly, when doing an installation of the latest nvidia driver I got a bunch of errors due to the keyboard-configuration package.

I tried to remove it and re-install it by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get rempove keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration
```

It didn't work, here is the error I get during the install:

```
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.142ubuntu2) ...
/usr/local/bin/setupcon: 806: /usr/local/bin/setupcon: /usr/local/bin/ckbcomp: not found
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I looked what the ckbcomp file is and it seems like it comes from the console-setup package, but if I try to install this package I get the same error as above with some additional failing packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install console-setup
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxatracker2 libxfont1 libxvmc1 xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xserver-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  console-setup-linux kbd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  console-setup console-setup-linux kbd
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,316 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,975 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package kbd.
(Reading database ... 412842 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kbd_2.0.3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kbd (2.0.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package console-setup-linux.
Preparing to unpack .../console-setup-linux_1.142ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking console-setup-linux (1.142ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package console-setup.
Preparing to unpack .../console-setup_1.142ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking console-setup (1.142ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-5ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.142ubuntu2) ...
/usr/local/bin/setupcon: 806: /usr/local/bin/setupcon: /usr/local/bin/ckbcomp: not found
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.142ubuntu2); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kbd:
 kbd depends on console-setup | console-setup-mini; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-mini is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kbd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on kbd (>= 1.15-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package kbd is not configured yet.
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.142ubuntu2); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency probNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                lems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there a way to make this work ? Looking for any ideas, I'm not that familiar with Linux, so it could originate from something I did wrong. The system was pretty stable before the update, never had any issue with it.

Comment: same issue here, does someone have a fix @Jeremy ?
@DavidFoerster for me `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`gives:  `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: keyboard-configuration is broken or not fully installed`

Comment: @Louis: If you have a different question please open a new question. The underlying issue may very well be different in your case and the comment section is ill suited for new questions or extended discussion. Notify me [in chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you want to draw my attention to it.

Comment: Your Apt uses a really weird version of the `console-setup` package (1.142). It should be 1.108 in Xenial (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/console-setup). Could you please provide the output of `apt-cache policy console-setup`?

Comment: Is `rempove` a typo?