# unmet dependencies - keyboard-configuration

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Having issues with keyboard-confiugration...tried to reconfigure dpkg without success. Hesitant to try remove...

Similar to (perhaps same as?)
[After Ubuntu update from 15 to 16.04, error in keyboard-configuration package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770920/after-ubuntu-update-from-15-to-16-04-error-in-keyboard-configuration-package)

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.2) but 1.156 is to be installed
nodejs : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libuv1 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: *Try `apt-get -f install` with no packages* - Just saying :)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Ah, I thought -f was force and skip problem but it is actually --fix-broken...

When I ran that I got a different problem
`dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Edit: There are still errors as noted above, but installation is working..Thanks for the pointer folks!

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue on Xubuntu 16.04.  My resolution was to rename /etc/default/keyboard and /etc/default/console-setup, then run sudo apt-get -f install. This corrected the errors in setting up keyboard-configuration, console-setup-linux, and console-setup.